# Change font color of insensitive GtkToggleButton through CSS

Tags: css, button, user-interface, gtk, stylesheet

I am trying to style a button in a Gtk program using CSS.
Everything works quite well, except for one thing: I'd like to make the font black when the button is insensitive, overriding the light grey default one, but I can't make it work.
Here is my CSS file:

```
GtkToggleButton#togglebuttonuser:insensitive {
    background: #729fcf;
    background-color: #729fcf;
    color: black;
}
```

But when the button goes into insensitive state here is how it looks:

[image]

So, background color is applied correctly, but font remains grey... where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't know the `:insensitive` pseudo selector. Did you mean `:disabled`? Check the element with developer tools to see if the rule you provided is really beeing applied.

Comment: Yes, in GTK+'s CSS setup, the disabled selector is `:insensitive`. Likewise, the function to enable/disable a control is `gtk_widget_set_sensitive()`. It's an X11 thing, I believe.

Comment: Exactly, I also tried with `:disabled`, but it's not working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the selector `#togglebuttonuser:insensitive *` (recent GTK versions) or `#togglebuttonuser *:insensitive` (earlier GTK versions).